# Deriving $\sqrt{b^2+2gs}$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

I was trying to derive this problem for quite some time and I was unable to do it. As a result, I checked the solution on how to do it but there is one step that doesn't make sense.

**Question:** An object moves so that its velocity, *v*, is related to its position, *s*, according to $v=\sqrt{2gs+b^2}$, where *b* and *g* are constants. Show that the acceleration of the object is constant.

**Solution:** 
$$v=\sqrt{b^2+2gs}           \tag{1}$$
$$v=(b^2+2gs)^{1/2}                \tag{2}$$
$$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{2}(b^2+2gs)^{-1/2}\;\times\; (0+2g\dfrac{ds}{dt})           \tag{3}$$
$$a=\dfrac{1}{2v}\;\times\; (2gv)           \tag{4}$$
$$a=g           \tag{5}$$
The part I don't understand is the transition from$\;(3)\;$to $\;(4)\;$. How does the derivative of $\dfrac{ds}{dt} = v$? That line makes no sense.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit sorry about that. I messed up with the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition — the velocity $v$ is the derivative $\frac{ds}{dt}$ of the position function $s$.

Comment: I just noticed that 30 s ago